# py-appscript expects arguments

Tags: python, arguments, vlc, sourceforge-appscript

I want to make a Python script to control VLC. VLC can be controlled through AppleScript and by using [`py-appscript`](http://appscript.sourceforge.net/) I can run AppleScript code from Python.

Using AppleScript I can play/pause VLC by

```
tell application "VLC" to play
```

This equals to the following in `py-appscript`

```
app('VLC').play()
```

I should also be able to skip to next track by:

```
app('VLC').next()
```

But when doing so I get the following Python error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "vlclib.py", line 25, in <module>
    app('VLC').next()
TypeError: next() takes exactly 2 arguments (1 given)
```

Does anyone know why I get this error? The above code should equal the following in AppleScript which works perfectly:

```
tell application "VLC" to next
```

Comment: Could you post the output of running `help(app('VLC').next)` on line 24 in your script?

Comment: This gives me the following. `Help on method next in module appscript.reference: next(self, klass) method of appscript.reference.Application instance` It is as if it thinks `next()` exists in `py-appscript` but `next()` should call VLC through AppleScript.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the [appscript documentation](http://appscript.sourceforge.net/py-appscript/doc_3x/appscript-manual/05_keywordconversion.html):

> Names that match Python keywords or names reserved by appscript have an underscore appended.

As `next` is a reserved keyword, you can fix this by running

```
app('VLC').next_()
```

Comment: Ah, of course! I guess I didn't think about `next` being a keyword but of course it is. Actually, it is `app('VLC').next_()`

Comment: Durr... :). I updated the answer to match the documentation. Thanks!